# Can I use my Windows Phone as remote for my unity3d game?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I want to use my windows phone as a input device for unity3d game in pc. 
As per my plan , I was thinking to send accelerometer values over wifi to local server in my laptop and then to retreive values from local server from inside unity3d by network calls. Is this a viable option? 
What can be other methods to get this thing done?
If any other game development platform supports such operation then please help with information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible but I guess you need to do that by your own. I know no frameworks which does that job for you. You need to implement a fast network communication for low delay and you also need a Windows Phone App which passes the data to your server.

In best case you should implement also a automatic server discovery via broad- or multicast. Without that the acceptance of the users will be bad.

Comment: exactly ,,.,as I am using local server ...the network communication will be fast... But is there anything in unity where I can directly connect the two using bluetooth or wifi?

Comment: Not as far I know. However WiFi and Bluetooth can be very slow. Keep in mind that you have about 16ms for 60fps and in that time must be the input changes also handled.